# SSl Certificates import need to be done in Tomcat or JDK

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https

I'm new to SSL connectivity, i have deployed on J2EE application in Tomcat Server.
From my Application i'm sending RestCall to other app by https.Also doing file transfer to other domain using https connection.

My question is , I got the SSl CA certificates for other domains, i donno whether i have to import these CA  certificates to JDK level cacerts or Tomcat level.

I donno both way we can achieve this or not, i got confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it either way.  But the Tomcat documentation explains how to create a custom keystore, populate it, and configure a Tomcat connector to use it; refer to the [Tomcat SSL/TLS Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) for details.

It makes more sense to keep your server certs out of the JDK / JRE installation.  For a start, it means that you don't need to re-import the certs each time you update your Java install.

It also makes sense to import any other certs that the server requires into the server keystore you just created.  Depending on how you implement the webapp's HTTPS (etc) client capability, you could either use the custom keystore directly, or by making that keystore the Tomcat JVM's default keystore by adding `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path>` to the Tomcat launch options.